# Add query string value when html page is launched from Java Controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, post, query-string

I have a HTML page that is launched from a java controller after a post and I want to attach a query string value in the url ex: (localhost:8000/gdata?id=11).  Can this be done?  Here is my controller code:

```
package com.sa.example;

import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
//import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import com.sentinel.advisor.GData;
import com.sentinel.advisor.GDataJdbcRepository;

@Controller
public class GDataController {

    @Autowired
    GDataJdbcRepository repository;

    @GetMapping("/gdata")
    public String gDataForm(Model model) {
        return "gData";
    }

    @PostMapping("/gdata")
    public String gDataSubmit(@ModelAttribute GData gData) {
        String returnString = repository.insert(gData);
        //returnString should be returned in the url as a query string
        return "result";
    }

}
```

Comment: You can use a redirect (as it is best practice to after post anyway) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get. Spring's redirect view: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/RedirectView.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a redirect (it is best practice to redirect after post regardless see - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get.

Spring's redirect view:

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/RedirectView.html

Something like:

```
@Controller
public class GDataController {

    @Autowired
    GDataJdbcRepository repository;

    @GetMapping("/gdata")
    public String gDataForm(Model model) {
        return "gData";
    }

    @PostMapping("/gdata")
    public RedirectView gDataSubmit(@ModelAttribute GData gData) {
        String returnString = repository.insert(gData);
        return new RedirectView("/sucess?returnString=" + returnString, true);
    }

    @GetMapping("/success")
    public String getResultPage(@RequestParam("returnString")String returnString){
        return "result";
    }
}
```